# Is there any way block or detect files upload via web browser?

Tags: c#, .net

I am designing a proxy server to block file upload or download request made by user.
Is there any way to detect file upload or download request URL in HTTP/HTTPs header?

I tried with `content-type=octet-stream` in HTTPS header, but not working:

```
foreach (var header in eventArgs.WebSession.Request.RequestHeaders) { 
    string value;

    if (header.Key.Equals("Content-Type")) {
        if (header.Value.Value.Contains("octet-stream")) await eventArgs.Ok("");
    }
}
```

`eventArgs` containing Session Info in it like Request, Response etc.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: I tried with content-type=octet-stream in HTTPS header, but not working

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: foreach (var header in eventArgs.WebSession.Request.RequestHeaders)
                    {

                        string value;
                        if (header.Key.Equals("Content-Type"))
                        {
                            if (header.Value.Value.Contains("octet-stream"))
                                await eventArgs.Ok("");
                        }
                    }

Comment: eventArgs containing Session Info in it like Request, Response etc

Comment: Is there any information in request header part so that I can identify that the particular request is for upload/download.

Comment: Note that you need to perform a man-in-the-middle attack to do this on HTTPS connections. Watch out for potential browser warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header and parse for the filename directive. This directive is

> followed by a string containing the original name of the file
>   transmitted

in a multipart/form-data submission

Comment: But if we are going to upload a file on google drive or dropbox they don't use content-type="multipart/form-data" and Content-Disposition header. I used fiddler to trace http/https requests, and I didn't find this info in while uploading on google drive/dropbox.